# Twilio Agent Conference

Tags: twilio-api

I am trying to create a agent conferencing. I have went through different doc and examples but i am bit confused. 
Scenario is that i have to make call center for both incoming and outgoing calls.
1. For incoming calls customer will call . An agent will there to handle the call. Now how can I add supervisor  to it. and make him mute, whisper and barge. what if supervisor will not take the call.
Same for the outgoing call.
The main problem where I am stuck is that how to add supervisor and make him mute and whisper.
I have worked on its most of the part but only confusion is on adding supervisor.
I have used Rest Api (PHP) to add participants.

First I have created a TwimL Application and gave a voice url. which have this xml code below.

1) voiceurl.php

```
<Response>
<Dial callerId='+123456' action="recordURL.php" method="POST">
<Number statusCallback = "www.demo.com/answered_callback.php"
statusCallbackEvent = "answered"
statusCallbackMethod = "POST">+00000000?></Number>
</Dial>
<Say>ThankYou</Say>
</Response>
```

2) answeredCallback.php

```
$twilio = new Client($acct_sid, $auth_token);

$client = new Services_Twilio($acct_sid, $auth_token);

    $call = $client->account->calls->get($child_call_sid);
    $call->update(array(
        "Url" => "www.demo.com/conference.php",
        "Method" => "POST"
    ));
```

3) Conference.php

```
<?php echo '<Response>
<Dial record="record-from-answer-dual">
<Conference beep="false" muted="false" waitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical" 
record = "record-from-start"
recordingStatusCallback = "recording_callback.php"
recordingStatusCallbackMethod = "POST"
startConferenceOnEnter="true" 
endConferenceOnExit="false" 
statusCallback="conference_callback.php" 
statusCallbackMethod="POST" 
statusCallbackEvent="start end">TwidiosConference
</Conference>
</Dial>
</Response>';
```

I have another doubt with twilio device disconnect():-

I am connecting the call through JS with twilio.device.connect(). i am using Twilio.Device.disconnectAll() method for disconnect, This works perfect for single call. but When creating a conference call it does not disconnect the connected calls. I want here to disconnect all connected devices with the same conference hub.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thankyou.